# PBS jobs vs PBS job-arrays

Tags: pbs

What is the difference between submitting individual jobs as PBS scripts and submitting them as a single PBS-array? (I am getting a significant run-time improvement for the latter)

Comment: I know this is an old question, but what do you mean by significant run-time improvement?  I believe the answer to this question depends on how you are measuring.